# How do you open a file that is stored as blob in the db (SQL server) in new browser window?

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server, blob, data-retrieval

When opening a file in new browser window that is stored in the file system with the url stored in the database, the solution is simple with the javascript method:

```
[var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName\[, strWindowFeatures\]);][1]
```

However, when storing files as blob in the database (SQL Server) there is no url pointing to the file. What is the best practice for retrieving the file for the user? Do I need to copy the file to a temp folder and then provide the url dynamically? Then delete the file after a certain point?

I know that storing the file in the file system would be easier to code, but I have chosen to store it as a blob for all the benefits that come with a DBMS.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your web server will have to write the BLOB's bytes to a response stream, plus an appropriate `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` header so that the browser knows how to treat those bytes. Use a tool like Fiddler and browse to google.com. You can see what Google's responses contains for images on the page. Your goal is to generate a response in a similar fashion.

Comment: I will have to look into Fiddler. I am already using Response.BinaryWrite(myDocument.FileBLOB.ToArray()); This downloads the file for the user. I am trying to open the file in a new browser window. Thanks for your response Nathan.